# Problem with LSParseDateTime function on server only despite server locale correctly set

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, locale

When I run this test code on my development machine it works as expected. CF9.01

I am in europe using euro date format so 10/09/1957 is 10th Sept 1957.

```
<cfset testDate="10/09/1957">
<cfoutput>
Initial string = "#testDate#"<br>
LSparsedatetime output = #lsparsedatetime(session.form.patientDOB)#<br>
parsedatetime output = #parsedatetime(session.form.patientDOB)#
</cfoutput>
```

Output on test machine is

> ```
> Initial string = "10/09/1957"
> LSparsedatetime output = {ts '1957-09-10 00:00:00'}
> parsedatetime output = {ts '1957-10-09 00:00:00'}
> ```

Same code , output on live server is

```
Initial string = "10/09/1957"
LSparsedatetime output = {ts '1957-10-09 00:00:00'} 
parsedatetime output = {ts '1957-10-09 00:00:00'}
```

Server OS is Windows Web Server 2008 R2. I checked Control panel > date and time setting and it is correctly set to London. Web server is IIS7 but I don't think that would affect anything?

IN region and Language, location is set to United Kingdom and in Administrative (change system locale ) it is also correct as English (United Kingdom)

Update : as far as CF is concerned it thinks the server is on US locale.

Running this ...

```
<cfset testDate="10/09/1957">
<cfoutput>
Initial string = "#testDate#"<br>
#getLocale()#:<br>
LSparsedatetime output = #lsparsedatetime(testDate)#<br>
parsedatetime output = #parsedatetime(testDate)#<br>
<P>
<cfset SetLocale("en_GB") />
en_GB:<br>
LSparsedatetime output = #lsparsedatetime(testDate)#<br>
parsedatetime output = #parsedatetime(testDate)#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

Gives this output

```
Initial string = "10/09/1957"
English (US):
LSparsedatetime output = {ts '1957-10-09 00:00:00'}
parsedatetime output = {ts '1957-10-09 00:00:00'}
en_GB:
LSparsedatetime output = {ts '1957-09-10 00:00:00'}
parsedatetime output = {ts '1957-10-09 00:00:00'}
```

But here's confirmation of the server settings.

[image]
[image]

Forcing locale with setLocale in the code resolves to correct behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to force the locale using `SetLocale`, consider this sample:

```
<cfset testDate="10/09/1957">
<cfoutput>
Initial string = "#testDate#"<br>
#getLocale()#:<br>
LSparsedatetime output = #lsparsedatetime(testDate)#<br>
parsedatetime output = #parsedatetime(testDate)#<br>
<cfset SetLocale("en_US") />
en_US:<br>
LSparsedatetime output = #lsparsedatetime(testDate)#<br>
parsedatetime output = #parsedatetime(testDate)#<br>
<cfset SetLocale("en_GB") />
en_GB:<br>
LSparsedatetime output = #lsparsedatetime(testDate)#<br>
parsedatetime output = #parsedatetime(testDate)#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

I'm in Ukraine, so the output looks as follows:

```
Initial string = "10/09/1957"
uk_UA:
LSparsedatetime output = {ts '1957-09-10 00:00:00'}
parsedatetime output = {ts '1957-10-09 00:00:00'}
en_US:
LSparsedatetime output = {ts '1957-10-09 00:00:00'}
parsedatetime output = {ts '1957-10-09 00:00:00'}
en_GB:
LSparsedatetime output = {ts '1957-09-10 00:00:00'}
parsedatetime output = {ts '1957-10-09 00:00:00'}
```

Obviously, `ParseDateTime` works the same with any locale, but `LSParseDateTime` does the needed job.

Comment: Thanks Sergii, forcing the locale works. Strangely CF thinks the server is on US locale despite my settings, using setlocale makes it work correctly.

Comment: So it WAS the locale :) +1 for setLocale().

Answer (score 1):

I thinnk this is to do with your **locale**, not your timezone.

Your locale on your live server appears to be set to US as it is seeing 10/09/1957 as the 9th of October whereas your test server sees it UK style, i.e. the 10th of September.

You'll need to compare the local setting on the servers.

Try Region & Language -> Administrative (Tab) -> Change System Locale and compare.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I looked at that Ciaran and it appears correctly set. Added that to question

Comment: Have you tired forcing locale as per the other post? The month/date mix-up looks very suspicious.